# Question about brace-initialization of data member array in constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17

In the following class:

```
struct S {
    S() : B{} {}

    const uint8_t B[32];
};
```

Are all 32 bytes of the `B` array guaranteed to be initialized to zero by the default constructor?

Is there any way to create an object of type `S` such that any element of the `B` array is not zero?  (without const casting or reinterpretting memory).  Do all forms of initialization of `S` lead to a zeroed `B` array?

Comment: Can you give an example on how would you like to initialize `S::B`, other than zeroing it?

Comment: @paolo I think the desire is to avoid uninitialized bytes, and not to initialize the bytes to particular non-zero values.

Comment: @paolo: There are several different kinds of initialization in C++, could any of them yield an S object with a non-zero B array element?

Comment: I get the question now, thanks.

Comment: BTW, after the array has been filled with zeros, what are you going to do with them? Any attempt to change them later is undefined behavior. No form of const_casting will get around it.

Comment: @j6t: It's a toy example to understand the language mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are all 32 bytes of the B array guaranteed to be initialized to zero by the default constructor?

Yes, `B` is value-initialized which for an array means each member is value-initialized - primitive types are value-initialized to 0.

> Is there any way to create an object of type S such that any element of the B array is not zero?

Not as far as I know, although `S` still has the default copy constructor so if somehow you got an `S` with non-zero `B`, you can clone those objects.

- `const` member guarantees the values cannot be changed throughout the lifetime, so any non-zero value must be set at initialization which leads to the third question...

> Do all forms of initialization of S lead to a zeroed B array?

Yes, `S` is not an aggregate (due to user-provided ctor) so there is no way how to initialize the members directly.